# What's the correct way to reference a helper in a rails controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Sometimes I need to use helper methods in controllers (sanitization methods, rendering text back to the view, various other applications). What's the right way? I've got:

- `self.class.helpers.myhelper`
- `view_context.myhelper`
- `include MyHelper; myhelper`
- `helper MyHelper; myhelper`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [`ActionController::Base.helpers`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Helpers/ClassMethods.html#method-i-helpers) is the gold standard; you might want to wrap it in a method for convenience:

  ```
  private

  def helpers
    ActionController::Base.helpers           
  end
  ```
- `helper MyHelper`: if you're trying to isolate the helper to the scope of a single controller and don't want to keep typing `helpers` all over the place
- Avoid `view_context` it instantiates a view instance per call and assumes you're necessarily using `ActionView`
- Avoid `self.class.helpers.myhelper` since this'll need to perform reflection to determine the current class
- Avoid `include MyHelper; myhelper` since this'll make all the helper methods controller actions

Comment: Any reason not to make that `ApplicationController.helpers` if AC inherits from `ActionController::Base`?

Comment: It doesn't really matter for as long as you're consistently using the same one since it's [lazily evaluated](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/719f1d68e4945332f71dc8ad93141780e60929b5/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/helpers.rb#L75).